# How to take the row ID of a Jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

Currently, the following process in javascript determines the row to be updated based on the rowId value, and then updates the row.

```
const rowData = $('#list').jqGrid('getRowData', rowId);
$('#list').jqGrid('setRowData', rowId, rowData);
$('#list').trigger('reloadGrid');
```

However, the rowId is finally unique based on the values of the four Jqgrid columns, so the following method is used to obtain the Jqgrid list data and then use the table ID to obtain the rowId.

```
let rowId;
for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  if (rows[i].cells[0].title.trim() === valueA
    && rows[i].cells[1].title.trim() === valueB
      && rows[i].cells[1].title.trim() === valueC
        && rows[i].cells[1].title.trim() === valueD) {
          rowId = $(rows[i]).closest('tr').attr('id');
          break;
    }
}
```

Initially, this method worked fine, but after using Jqgrid's Sort function, I tried to update the rows again, and as a result, different rows were updated.

I am afraid that the rowId of the target row cannot be obtained when the Sort function is used.
Is there any way to get the target row with or without Sort?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your last code

```
let rowId;
for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  if (rows[i].cells[0].title.trim() === valueA
    && rows[i].cells[1].title.trim() === valueB
      && rows[i].cells[1].title.trim() === valueC
        && rows[i].cells[1].title.trim() === valueD) {
          rowId = $(rows[i]).closest('tr').attr('id');
          break;
    }
}
```

your code relies on the presumption of rows[i], where rows[i] is the current position of the row. After sorting this position of course changes, so by example if the row with id = x was in position 3 - i.e rows[3], after sorting this rows changes and as a result mean that  different row can meet your criteria.

To check this you can simple change your code like this

```
let rowId, myArray=[];
for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  if (rows[i].cells[0].title.trim() === valueA
    && rows[i].cells[1].title.trim() === valueB
      && rows[i].cells[1].title.trim() === valueC
        && rows[i].cells[1].title.trim() === valueD) {
          rowId = $(rows[i]).closest('tr').attr('id');
          myArray.push(rowId);
    }
}
console.log(myArray)
```

Maybe you will see more that one id which meet this criteria.